# Consider this Cauchy Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, cauchy-problem

Consider the Cauchy problem

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{t} - \kappa u_{xx}=0 & \quad \mbox{$x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0$,}\\
\quad u(x,0) = \psi(x), \end{array} \right. $$

where $\kappa > 0$ is a constant, and $\psi (x)$ is an ${even}$ function. Show that the solution $u$ is even in $x$ for all $t>0$. i.e., $u(x,t) = u(-x,t)$.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's true in this generality: in order to have uniqueness in the Cauchy problem you need to impose suitable bounds on $u$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, I have mistyped the equation. There should have been a negative instead of a positive $\kappa u_{xx}$. I have corrected it. That would change the scenario, yes?

Comment: Actually I didn't notice the wrong sign.  The comment still stands.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion in the comments insists on the fact that uniqueness is obtained provided that we have two constants $A, a > 0$ such that
$$
|u(x,t)| \leq A e^{a |x|^2} \, , \qquad
x\in\Bbb R,\, t\in [0,T] \, .
$$
If this is satisfied, then one can speak of *the solution*.

That being said, if we set $\xi = -x$, we have $u_\xi = -u_x$, and $u_{\xi\xi} = u_{xx}$. Since $\psi$ is an even function, we have $\psi(\xi) = \psi(x)$. Therefore,
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
u_t - \kappa u_{\xi\xi} &= 0 \, ,\\
u(\xi,0) &= \psi(\xi) \, ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad
\xi\in\Bbb R,\, t\in [0,T] \, .
$$
The bound on the solution is unchanged too: $|u(\xi,t)| \leq A e^{a|\xi|^2}$. Therefore, the PDE problem for $u(\xi,t)$ is the same as for $u(x,t)$. From uniqueness of the solution, we conclude that $u(\xi,t) = u(x,t)$.